# How to integrate VMWare Tools onto a Windows installation image

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-vsphere

I don't know if I can integrate VMWare Tools onto a Windows Server 2008 R2 iso image so that I do not need to install it every time after a fresh OS installation on ESXi based VM. Which tools should I choose? Windows System Image Manager (WSIM) or any other thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just install it into a prebuilt template and then just use 'deploy from template', works a treat.

Comment: I was tempted to write the same but the question is about making changes to the installation image specifically. Also if I remember correctly templating works only with vCenter and this may be not a case here...